# Upload an image to webserver using HTML POST

Tags: html, vb.net, post

I'm trying to make a screen capturing program which uploads it straight to one of the servers after. Unfortunately everything I tried either gave me errors or didn't work out at all.

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp
    Form2.Hide()
    Me.Hide()
    Dim bounds As Form2
    Dim screenshot As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Dim graph As Graphics
    bounds = Form2
    screenshot = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb)
    graph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
    graph.CopyFromScreen(Form2.Bounds.X, Form2.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
    Form2.BackgroundImage = screenshot
    Using sendto As New Net.WebClient
        Dim param As New Specialized.NameValueCollection
        param.Add("userfile", screenshot)
        Dim response_bytes = sendto.UploadValues("http://www.directimg.eu/index.php", "POST", param)
        Dim response_body = (New Text.UTF8Encoding).GetString(response_bytes)
    End Using
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

This is my current code, unfortunately it doesn't work because "screenshot" needs to be a string.
I hope I can be helped out!

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the `UploadFile` method of `Net.WebClient`? See examples here: http://chiragvidani.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-uploaddownload-file-tofrom.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send images in POST data you convert them to a Base64 string. But first you must get the image bytes. Here is an example, I have modified as necessary because I do not have your forms but you should be able to follow it:

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim screenshot As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Dim graph As Graphics

    screenshot = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(400, 400, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb)
    graph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)

    graph.CopyFromScreen(20, 500, 0, 0, New Size(400, 400), CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)

    Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
    screenshot.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)

    'screenshot.Save("c:\deleteme\screenshot.png")

    Dim imgBytes As Byte() = ms.ToArray()
    Dim imgStr As String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(imgBytes)

    Using sendto As New Net.WebClient
        Dim param As New Specialized.NameValueCollection
        param.Add("userfile", imgStr)
        Dim response_bytes = sendto.UploadValues("http://www.directimg.eu/index.php", "POST", param)
        Dim response_body = (New System.Text.UTF8Encoding).GetString(response_bytes)
    End Using

End Sub

End Module
```